# Rooting android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, root

The problem is that, when I write "su" in terminal emualator, I have "su:uid 10032 not allowed to su". So why I need to root the emulator?

Comment: what you exactly want to do? Be more ellaborative other than asking question with very short detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be root when you log into emulator:

```
$ adb shell
# ps
...
root     271   37    740   312   c003b100 afe0d14c S /system/bin/sh
...
#
```

What do you get on the sh ps line?

Comment: Can you explain little more and where should i write adb shell?

Comment: You'll find adb in the platform-tools folder in the Android SDK installation. Which platform (windows/unix/mac) do you use?

Comment: thanx for answering man... m using windows and position of adb is no issue. what i was trying to ask was when to run... like just run the emulator and then perform this command... ?

Comment: Yup. Just start the emulator; then run the windows cmd -shell and start 'adb shell' from the platform-tools folder.

Comment: 293 292 868 323 00000000 afe0c7dc R ps